# Export Certificate - with or without the private key

Tags: security, ssl, http-headers, ssl-certificate

I am relatively new to SSL.  When you export a certificate; there are two options:

```
1) Export the Private Key
2) Do not export the private key
```

I assume that you export with the private key when you want to move the certificate from one server to another.  When would you export without the private key?

Also, say you want to trust a certificate.  Do you 'copy and paste' or 'cut and paste' the certificate from Personal/Certificates to Trusted People/Certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is a protocol and not an implementation, so I don't know what kind of software you are using. However, I can tell you that you might want to export without the private key if for example you're already on your server (you generated the keys on it I mean) and you want to distribute the public key.

It doesn't matter if you copy or cut, but I suggest you to copy to have a backup just in case you want to delete all the trusted certs.